# How to change .pch file location(Visual Studio 2008)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, precompiled-headers, pch

my project has a lot of pch files.
So, when I build projects, it makes .pch files a lot at Local\Temp\c\Vs2008...
Because I have small capacity harddisk, I want to change the destination of .pch file generated.
How to change .pch file location?
I use Visual Studio 2008.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1) Select Properties on the project

2) Navigate to Configuration Properties / C++ / Precompiled Headers

3) Change the value of Precompiled Header File. You can also use the dropdown to use macros for the location.